# How to create a WPF TabControl with multiple headers per TabItem?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

**Description:**

Currently I'm in the process of creating a WPF application where the main content should be presented in a TabControl.

The TabControl exists of:

- A TabItem that contains an external control which has multiple views, whereby each view should be visible as Header on the TabControl;
- Multiple TabItems with our own content, each one with it's own header.

Styling of WPF controls is not the problem, but this case requires some special behaviour of the control itself. The problem is that the control should render multiple Headers per TabItem.

**Questions:**

- What is the best control to use for such a scenario?
- If using TabControl, what modifications should be made?

Thanks in advance.

**Update #1**

In response to vortex a prototype of such a control (as you can see, the external control is the Microsoft Office InfoPath FormControl):

```
   <TabControl x:Name="FormViewsTabControl">
      <TabItem>
         <TabItem.Headers>
            <TabItemHeader Text="View A" />
            <TabItemHeader Text="View B" />
         </TabItem.Headers>
         <TabItem.Content>
            <winforms:WindowsFormsHost x:Name="InfoPathFormsHost">
               <infopath:FormControl x:Name="InfoPathFormControl" />
            </winforms:WindowsFormsHost>
         </TabItem.Content>
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem Header="Letter">
         <local:CustomView />
      </TabItem>
   </TabControl>
```

Comment: Could you provide some prototype or sketch of such control? I can't imagine a tab item with multiple headers.

Comment: @vorrtex please see the updated post with such a prototype.

Comment: Still don't get it. Do you want to place the view A below the view B? Or above? Or to the left? What if there are more views than two?

Comment: @vorrtext, Aside, from left to right, just the same as the other TabItem Headers in the TabControl. If there are more than two, than they should be added to the right.

Comment: Ok, then the answer of @Amry must solve your needs. Except that you should change the open tag to `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">`, and I would also set the HeaderTemplate property instead of the Header and use a DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it correctly then you would like to change the TabItems header depending on which view you select in your external control. If that's the case then you should try to expand your external control with a property which holds the actual header value and then bind this to the TabItmes header.

Comment: Your suggestion is doable, but I've an additional question. Not only do I need the actual header value, I also need the other view names (of inactive views) of the external control.

Comment: Then you would like to see all the view names in the TabItems header but would like to distinguish the selected one. That sounds a bit harder but maybe you could create a dataTemplate for the TabItems header that it has a listbox and then bind the view list to it and the selectedItem to the actually selected view, and you could even style the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it so that the TabItem.Header contains a Panel element, which can contain multiple child elements. Example:

```
<TabItem>
  <TabItem.Header>
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="View A" />
      <TextBlock Text="View B" />
    </StackPanel>
  </TabItem.Header>
  <TabItem.Content>
    <winforms:WindowsFormsHost x:Name="InfoPathFormsHost">
      <infopath:FormControl x:Name="InfoPathFormControl" />
    </winforms:WindowsFormsHost>
  </TabItem.Content>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Allright, I like it this simple! But how do you get consistent TabItem Header styling with this solution?

Comment: See my opening post, consistent as in headers 'View A' and 'View B' look the same as header 'Letter'.

Comment: As @vorrtex said, you can have a left to right appearance by changing the opening tag to `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">`. And using the HeaderTemplate would be better since the header text will not be hardcoded. Definition of the HeaderTemplate binding will base on how the list of views can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

We used the following link

[http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/using-contenttemplateselector/]

when we faced with these type of issue

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.